# how to extract data from a XML doc

Tags: php, xml

```
 $xml=simplexml_load_string($lists) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

gives:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [list] => Array ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [id] => 8 
                [name] => #1 
                [subscriber_count] => 210 
                [display_name] => Display name 
            ) 
        ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [id] => 9 
                [name] => #2 No External Promotions 
                [subscriber_count] => 2242 
                [display_name] => Display name 
            ) 
        ) 
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [@attributes] => Array ( 
                [id] => 939036 
                [name] => #1 No Internal Promotions 
                [subscriber_count] => 3301 
                [display_name] => Display name 
        ) 
    )
)
```

how do I use a foreach loop to extract 'id' and other info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Recommended section in the PHP manual: [Basic SimpleXML usage](https://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access data you need to know about xml structure. As I see from dump you can access all first list node's attributes like this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($lists) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->list[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

For all nodes example:

```
foreach($xml->list as $list){
    echo (string) $list, "\n";
    foreach($list->attributes() as $a => $b) {
       echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I specify to get just say the [id]? I need to then run a query to insert the info in the database so I need each attribute individually.